# SQL Select DISTINCT ID where Description contains certain text value

Tags: sql, sql-server, distinct

I have a table that contains the following sample data:-

```
ID     Description
1      John Doe
2      Jane Doe
3      RETRO John Doe
3      John Doe
4      Jane Doe
4      RETRO Jane Doe
5      Bobby
```

ID column is not a primary key hence the duplicate ID's

I want to select all the records from the above table, but where an ID is duplicated i only want to select the record that starts with 'RETRO' and ignore the other record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT ID, DESCRIPTION FROM Table 
WHERE Description LIKE 'RETRO %' 
OR ID IN (
   SELECT ID FROM Table GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
select * from tablename where Description like 'RETRO%' and ID in (select ID from tablename group by ID having count(ID) > 1)
UNION ALL
select * from tablename where ID not in (select ID from tablename group by ID having count(ID) > 1)
order by ID, Description
```

Answer (score 0):

An option without the UNION:

```
select 
    id, 
    case 
        when (count(*) =1) then max(sd.name) 
        else (select sd2.name from sampleData sd2 where sd2.id=sd.id and name like 'Retro%')
    end

from sampledata SD
group by id
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is probably simplest:

```
SELECT ID, Description
FROM (SELECT ID, Description
    FROM TABLE
    ORDER BY Description LIKE 'RETRO%' DESC, Description ASC) a
GROUP BY ID
```

This will sort the data so that rows where `Description` begins with `RETRO` are highest, so that this value is used when grouping by `ID`.